# Should have a cancel button when the action itself is to cancel

Tags: error-message, dialog, close, textbox, cancel

[image]
This is a dialogue box from an employee scheduling application. Here, the action to be performed is to Cancel the approved timesheet with a reason.
"Request cancellation" button is for cancelling the timesheet while "cancel" button is to go back.

The cancel button here confuses the user as the operation itself involves cancellation. What text do you think i can replace with the word cancel.

Answer (score 4):

You could use "Keep Timesheet" instead, since thats whats happening if the user is not requesting cancellation.

Or you could change the wording inside the dialog-box, maybe you could use "Delete timesheet" instead, im not sure since i don't know the exact context, that way you could keep "Cancel" for the button and keep it consistent (assuming you are using "Cancel"-Button on other dialogs too).

Comment: I don't think "delete" is synonymous to "cancel" in this case.

Comment: `Keep xxx` seems the best way to go IMO too in general: it states what the button does in an unanbiguous form.

Answer (score 1):

I think just renaming "Request cancelation" to "Request" and title to "Request timesheet cancelation" should work.

You should keep the cancel button on left, it is standard pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If this box is something that pops out or appears on another screen or after an action, you can use "close" ( to close the dialog) & "request cancellation" or "confirm cancellation" (depending on the process that follows after it)